# new List<A & ? extends B>();

Tags: java, generics, interface, abstract-class

If you know how to run the title line, just scroll down to **tl;dr** or write an answer!

I wrote the rest of the text to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It doesn't matter anymore, when this is done.

---

## Context

I want to create an object that takes a generic (List, Map, whatever).

The objects within the list should fullfill 2 criterias:

1. having `mymethod()` (which I realized from creating an Interface having this as a method head)
2. Extending `JComponent`

---

### How I tried to make this work:

1. I created multiple classes, any of these are implementing `MyInterface` and are extending a JComponent (subclasses of it). That's where I run in my title problem: `new List<MyInterface extends JComponent);`
2. Another idea: creating an abstract class (that fits all criteria) instead of an Interface. Problem: The concrete classes I need do not extend the same class.
3. I thought of Generics, just like: `public abstract class MyClass<X extends JComponent> extends X`, but this can't work – for obvious reasons. (e.g. I have to implement the abstract methods from a superclass, but if it's a Generic I cannot know by now.)

---

## tl;dr

I run in a problem which could easily be made if you can make this line working:

```
new List<A extends B>();
```

or, introduced by @khelwood:
    new List();

where:

- A is an Interface (just as I could declare a `new List<MyInterface>()`
- and any item extends `? extends B` (example: it can be a JTextField or a JTextArea or whatever they like, *but it has to be a (subclass of) JComponent* (JComponent = B))

Comment: I'm trying to follow what you are asking. Do you want a list in which each item extends both `A` and `B`?

Comment: @khelwood nearly. I want each item to extend `? extends A` (a JComponent or one of its subclasses) and to implement B.

Comment: @Asqiir If the concrete classes you speak of do not extend the same class then how can they extend `JComponent`?

Comment: @BartoszKP as explained in the edit, they do not extend the same class, but it's always a subclass of JComponent (so they can decide for JTextArea or JTextField or JRadioBox etc)

Comment: @Asqiir Your use of `List<A extends B>` is introducing confusion. Either type `A` extends type `B`, or it doesn't. If you actually want a type extending `A&B`, that is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to create a list of things which extend `JComponent` and implement your interface, and add things to such a list, you need to define a concrete type which implements both:

```
List<ThatType> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ThatType());
```

You can declare a type variable for this, in order to write a generic method:

```
<T extends JComponent & YourInterface> void something(T thing) {
  // ...
}
```

---

`<Something extends SomethingElse>` only works in the declarations of type variables.

Moreover, you don't create a list of `Somethings that extends SomethingElse`: you create a list of `Somethings`, and whether or not `Something extends SomethingElse` depends upon how those types are defined.

To make this more concrete, you don't make a `new List<String extends Object>`: you make a `List<String>`, and `String` happens to extend `Object`.

You need to declare the type variables appropriately, e.g.:

```
class Foo<B> {
  <A extends B> List<A> list() {
    return new List<>();
  }
}
```

Comment: `String` and `Object` is not a good analogy for what the OP is asking for. They need to assure that elements of a list both subclass `JComponent` *and* implement an unrelated interface at the same time.

Comment: @BartoszKP `extends` means they *aren't* unrelated.

Comment: I'm only restating what the OP wants, not whether it can be achieved using `extends`.

Comment: I really like your first code line, but my IDE marks it as an error (the `&`)

Comment: how do you want to create `ThatType`? ;-) Let's say: `class Concrete1 extends JTextField implements MyInterface` and `class Concrete2 extends JTextArea implements MyInterface`. Now, you propose an abstract class which both c1 and c2 are extending: `class ThatType extends ????? implements MyInterface`. Can you *please* tell me, what to place here without loosing the information about the JComponent? (**and to make the subclasses able to decide themselves which JComponent to extend?** Please note: I thought of this. You can find aspects in 2. and 3.)

Comment: "Now, you propose an abstract class which both c1 and c2 are extending" I say nothing about an abstract class. And `c1` and `c2` can't extend an abstract class if they already extend `JTextField` and `JTextArea`, except for any abstract class(es) they might both happen to extend already (like `JTextComponent`), because classes can only extend one class.

Answer (score 0):

You say that:

> Another idea: creating an abstract class (that fits all criteria) instead of an Interface. Problem: The concrete classes I need do not extend the same class.

but at the same time you say that they extend `JComponent`. The only possibility for this to occur is that they all transitively extend `JComponent`. So at some point up the inheritance hierarchy there is a direct inheritance from `JComponent`.

If this is still your code, this is the point where you could introduce another class, instead of a `JComponent` that extends `JComponent` and implements your interface.

If not then I think it could be impossible to achieve using only syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the type system allows you to do exactly what you want and get compile-time type safety.

One approximation is the following:

```
List<JComponent> componentList = new ArrayList<>();
List<MyInterface> myInterfaceList = (List) componentList;
```

If you don't mind the compile-time warning, you now have two views on the same list: one shows the content as `JComponent`'s and the other as `MyInterface`'s.

You can add the objects to either view and then read them from the view that provides the right type for the context.

Naturally, when you add an object the compiler will *not* check that the inserted object subclasses both `JComponent` and `MyInterface`. That is your responsibility.

If you want more (run-time) type safety, you can go this way:

```
List rawList = new ArrayList();
List checkedList = Collections.checkedList(rawList, JComponent.class);
List doublyCheckedList = Collections.checkedList(checkedList, MyInterface.class);
List<JComponent> componentList = doublyCheckedList;
List<MyInterface> myInterfaceList = doublyCheckedList;
```

If you only insert into `doublyCheckedList`, at runtime the list will check that the inserted objects subclass both `JComponent` and `MyInterface`. When reading, you can use the two views as in my previous fragment.